# Initialize jscolor after ajax post that resets form

Tags: jquery, ajax, jscolor

How do you run [jscolor](http://www.jscolor.com/) after an ajax post that resets a forms elements back to their default value?

The ajax below successfully posts to the in page iframe and restores in page form values to default when you click the "Restore Default" button. The problem is that the inputs that have jscolor attached to them don't change their background color back to their defaults.

The research I have done leads me to believe that I need to re-initiate jscolor with jscolor.init(); after the ajax post but I can't get it to work. I also tried building a function outside of the ajax post (that resets form values then jscolor.init();) and binding it to the "Restore Default" button with onclick but that didn't work.

**How can I get jscolor to run again after the ajax post?**

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#restore_form').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            data: $('#build_form').serialize(),
            type: $('#build_form').attr('method'),
            url: $('#build_form').attr('action')+'?type=restore',
            success: function(response) {
                $('#preview').contents().find('html').html(response);
                $('#build_form')[0].reset();
                jscolor.init();
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<iframe id="preview" src="preview.php" width="100%" height="120"></iframe>

<form id="build_form" class="build_form" action="preview.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="background_color" value="#0CA0E2" class="color {adjust:false,hash:true}" />
    <input id="restore_form" name="restore" type="submit" value="Restore Default" class="button" />
    <input id="save_form" name="submit" type="submit" value="Save Changes" class="button" />
</form>
```

Comment: Why don't you just reset the color?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to reset the color. Seeing your markup, I think that your default color is 0CA0E2. Am I corret? If so, you just need to (if you used the jscolor constructor and assign the new object to the myJsColorVar var):

```
myJsColorVar.color.fromString("0CA0E2"); // instead of jscolor.init()
```

In the docs, it is used:

```
document.getElementById("myColorInput").color.fromString("0CA0E2");
```

I think that the last example is better for you, since I saw that you didn't create your jscolor in JS, but applied the "color class".

You will just need to configure an id for your color input:

```
<form id="build_form" class="build_form" action="preview.php" method="post">
    <input id="myColorInput" type="text" name="background_color" value="#0CA0E2" class="color {adjust:false,hash:true}" />
    <input id="restore_form" name="restore" type="submit" value="Restore Default" class="button" />
    <input id="save_form" name="submit" type="submit" value="Save Changes" class="button" />
</form>
```

Take a look here: http://jscolor.com/try.php#setting-color

**Edit:** I created a custom jscolor.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>jscolor demo</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jscolor.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            function CustomJSColor( applyIn, defaultColor, opts ) {

                this.jscolor = new jscolor.color( document.getElementById( applyIn ), opts );
                this.defaultColor = defaultColor;
                this.jscolor.fromString( this.defaultColor );

                this.reset = function() {
                    this.jscolor.fromString( this.defaultColor );
                };

            }

        </script>
    <body>
        <input id="myField">
        <script>

            // the input with id "myField" will be the color picker
            // 0099cc is the default color
            // {} is the other options
            var myPicker = new CustomJSColor( "myField", "0099cc", {} );

            // to reset the color you just need to call reset
            myPicker.reset();

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I tried to inherit from jscolor.color but it seems that is not a constructor, so I created that class, that have one jscolor inside it. To reset the color of a component, you just need to call the reset method. Take care, because just using the "color" class will not create a CustomJSColor. You need to create it programmatically.

Comment: I thought about that; but I will be using the same script on many forms each with multiple color inputs. So I'm trying to avoid writing a specific script for each form.

Comment: But the default color will be always the same for every form?

Comment: The default color will be different for each input in each form.

Comment: Ok, but if the defaut color will be different, you won't be able to write a simpler code, since every form has its own colors. I think you should create a var with the default color and create the jscolors in JS, not in markup. I thinking in another solution. Just a moment...

Comment: Its been a while.. but today i'm getting:the following error
TypeError: document.getElementById(...).color is undefined  => when trying to implement your solution. any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old post, but I had the same issue and found a simpler solution, assuming that the form elements are jscolor inputs with the class 'color'

```
$('.color').each(function() {
    $(this).focus();
});
$('#someotherinput').focus();
```

Getting focus triggers the jscolor mojo and sets cell background and text color appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

By firing installByClassName by passing input class value

```
jscolor.installByClassName('jscolor');
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this as a good solution. After setting the value (JavaScript), I call this function:

```
document.getElementById('<your_id>').jscolor.importColor();
```

Then the new color is shown.